# Data won't export to excel file

Tags: python, excel, onedrive

I have a dataframe I'm trying to export to an excel file that lives on my company's SharePoint. I've mapped a network drive to the folder where the file is and used the following code to write to it:

`df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\companyname.sharepoint.com\Copy_Material Flow for XXX.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False)`

However, it's not writing anything to Sheet1 for some reason. Anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Try removing the `r` from `r'C:...` and use double quotes from single. Also, remove the spaces from the path.

Comment: I'm getting a unicode error if I do that. Before the script ran fine but just didn't output any data to the excel file @DogEatDog

Comment: you have to do "\\" in windows

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be the '`r'` in `r'path'`, try this:

```
df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Network Shortcuts\\companyname.sharepoint.com\\Copy_Material Flow for XXX.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False)
```

Comment: Hmm, the script runs but still outputs nothing to the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space from the filename first:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\companyname.sharepoint.com\Copy_MaterialFlowforXXX.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False)
```

Try removing the regular expression, `r`, from the string type

```
df.to_excel('C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\companyname.sharepoint.com\Copy_MaterialFlowforXXX.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False)
```

Comment: Might be worth reading up on [raw strings](//docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)?

Comment: Tried it and it runs but gives no output still. Could it be because my python script is in a different directory or should this have no impact?